# How to convert audio into an arrayBuffer using synchronous ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, html5-audio

```
var context = new webkitAudioContext();
var url = [ "/foo.mp3"];
function init(callback) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var audioBuffers = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
    req.open("GET", url[i], true);
    req.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    req.onload = function() {
      context.decodeAudioData(req.response, function(buffer) {
         //blah blah push buffer into an array
      });
    req.send();
    }

    if(callback) callback(audioBuffers);

}
```

This works fine, don't get me wrong. The thing is, I want it to load synchronously instead of asynchronously.

```
req.open("GET", url[i], true)
```

The last argument is where you declare it to be synchronous or not. For some reason, when I make it false, you are unable to change its responseType to an arraybuffer.

This then breaks the method since it is not an arraybuffer and cannot read the response. And is surprisingly natural behavior.

```
context.decodeAudioData(req.response, function(buffer){});
```

I did some reasearch on this, but I only found methods only to convert strings into an Array Buffer. **For this case, I am converting audio, like the mp3 format, into an arraybuffer while keeping the request synchronous.**
 Is there any workarounds for this?

Comment: Maybe this isn't possible. It might even be intentional - performing ajax synchronously is strongly discouraged.

Comment: But I dont really see the harm in it? Its just simple XMLHttpRequests and converting into an audioBuffer.

Comment: the harm is doing a sync operation will hang your browser for duration of its wait period - including shunting any currently rendering audio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the standard side. There's rumor (possibily true though) that synchronous request is going to be abandaned in future spec. New features are not surposed to support it. Check [this message](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/01/Getting-Rid-of-Synchronous-XHRs).

> The XMLHttpRequest2 spec was recently changed to prohibit sending a synchronous request when xhr.responseType is set.

Here's [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-XMLHttpRequest-20120117/#the-open-method):

> If **async is false**, there is an associated XMLHttpRequest document and either the timeout attribute value is not zero, the withCredentials attribute value is true, **or the responseType attribute value is not the empty string**, throw an "InvalidAccessError" exception and terminate these steps.

From the application side. Using `ArrayBuffer` usually means the resource you request is somehow a large binary. While synchronous request will block UI, that's really bad user experience. So even if you can do so, it's not a good idea either.

Comment: Hmm. I was trying to have all the files load first before my code is executed since there is code that depend on the files. If it does get executed before the load is not finished, the files will come out as undefined.

Comment: @user43353 You may need a resource management tool, like most HTML games do.